# SQL Command Not Properly Ended - Oracle Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, crystal-reports

I'm using a Crystal Reports 13 Add Command for record selection from an Oracle database connected through the Oracle 11g Client.  The error I am receiving is ORA-00933:  SQL command not properly ended, but I can't find anything the matter with my code (incomplete):

```
/*  Determine units with billing code effective dates in the previous month  */
SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "BILL"."EFF_DT"
FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS" ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" = "UNITS"."UNITID"
WHERE  "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" LIKE '580' AND TO_CHAR("BILL"."EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY')

INNER JOIN

/*  Loop through previously identified units and determine last billing code change prior to preious month  */
(
SELECT "BILL2"."UNIT_ID", MAX("BILL2"."EFF_DT")
FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL2"
WHERE TO_CHAR("BILL2"."EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') < TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY')
GROUP BY "BILL2"."UNIT_ID"
)

ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" = "BILL2"."UNIT_ID"
ORDER BY "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "BILL"."EFF_DT" DESC
```

We are a state entity that leases vehicles (units) to other agencies.  Each unit has a billing code with an associated effective date.  The application is to develop a report of units with billing codes changes in the previous month.

Complicating the matter is that for each unit above, the report must also show the latest billing code and associated effective date prior to the previous month.  A brief example:

Given this data and assuming it is now April 2016 (ordered for clarity)...

```
Unit    Billing Code    Effective Date  Excluded
----    ------------    --------------  --------
1       A               04/15/2016      Present month
1       B               03/29/2016
1       A               03/15/2016
1       C               03/02/2016
1       B               01/01/2015
2       C               03/25/2016
2       A               03/04/2016
2       B               07/24/2014
2       A               01/01/2014      A later effective date prior to previous month exists
3       D               11/28/2014      No billing code change during previous month
```

The report should return the following...

```
Unit    Billing Code    Effective Date
----    ------------    --------------
1       B               03/29/2016
1       A               03/15/2016
1       C               03/02/2016
1       B               01/01/2015
2       C               03/25/2016
2       A               03/04/2016
2       B               07/24/2014
```

Any assistance resolving the error will be appreciated.

Comment: `JOIN` clause cannot follow after `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `where` before `Join`  really matters to you, use a CTE. (Employing `with` clause for temporary table and joining on the same.)

```
  With c as (SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "BILL"."EFF_DT","BILL"."UNIT_ID"  -- Correction:  Was " BILL"."UNIT_ID" (spacetanker)
    FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL" -- Returning unit id column too, to be used in join

LEFT OUTER JOIN "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS" ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" = "UNITS"."UNITID"
    WHERE  "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" LIKE '580' AND TO_CHAR("BILL"."EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY'))

    select * from c     --Filter out your required columns from c and d alias results, e.g c.UNIT_ID
    INNER JOIN

    --Loop through previously identified units and determine last billing code change prior to preious month  */
    (
    SELECT "BILL2"."UNIT_ID", MAX("BILL2"."EFF_DT")
    FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL2"
    WHERE TO_CHAR("BILL2"."EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') < TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY')
    GROUP BY "BILL2"."UNIT_ID"
    ) d

    ON c."UNIT_ID" = d."UNIT_ID"
     order by c."UnitNumber", c."EFF_DT" desc  -- COrrection:  Removed semicolon that Crystal Reports didn't like (spacetanker)
```

It seems this query has lots of scope for tuning though. However, one who has access to the data and requirement specification is the best judge.

**EDIT :**
You are not able to see data PRIOR to previous month since you are using BILL.EFF_DT in your original question's select statement, which is filtered to give only dates of previous month(`..AND TO_CHAR("BILL"."EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY'))`

If you want the data as you want, I guess you have to use the BILL2 section (d part in my subquery), by giving an alias to Max(EFF_DT), and using that alias in your select clause.

Comment: @ IaB, thank you.  Your suggestions seems to incorporate the logic, however CR returns the dreaded SQL command not properly ended error when I try to execute it.  Looking at it in detail now.

Comment: @spacetanker,  I had misplaced the bill.unit_id in c. Edited.

Comment: @IaB.  Still receiving the same error message, unfortunately.

Comment: @spacetanker, is there anything in your code that you have not posted here? My query above looks fine to me.

Comment: @IaB, there were two issues.  First, the space in the  SELECT for "(space)BILL"."UNIT_ID".  I didn't catch that until I removed the semicolon (apparently Crystal Reports doesn't like them).  So the query is now running, however it still only shows the previous month's values; i.e., it doesn't show what the last effective date was the month PRIOR to the previous month.

Comment: @IaB, thank you for the input.  That has been precisely what I've been up to for days now.  Trying to do just that is what prompted this question - the SQL error I ran into along the way.  Seems a chicken vs. egg situation:  I need the max value to know where to begin, but using it excludes the very value I am trying to include.

Comment: @IaB, it took a few days to grind the problem down but your post started me in the correct direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `WHERE` clause before the `INNER JOIN` clause. This is invalid syntax - if you swap them it should work:

```
SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber",
       "BILL"."EFF_DT"
FROM   "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS"
       ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" = "UNITS"."UNITID"

INNER JOIN

/*  Loop through previously identified units and determine last billing code change prior to preious month  */
    (
    SELECT "UNIT_ID",
           MAX("EFF_DT")
    FROM   "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT"
    WHERE  TO_CHAR("EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') < TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY')
    GROUP BY "UNIT_ID"
    ) "BILL2"

    ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" = "BILL2"."UNIT_ID"
WHERE  "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" LIKE '580'
AND    TO_CHAR("BILL"."EFF_DT", 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'MMYYYY')
ORDER BY "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "BILL"."EFF_DT" DESC
```

Also, you need to move the `"BILL2"` alias outside the `()` brackets as you do not need the alias inside the brackets but you do outside.

Are you really sure you need the double-quotes `""`? Double-quotes enforce case sensitivity in column names - the default behaviour is for Oracle to convert all table and column names to upper case to abstract the case-sensitivity from the user - since you are using both double-quotes and upper-case names the quotes seems redundant.

Comment: @MTD Thank you.  I figured the syntax issue was staring me in the face.

It's undoubtedly in how I constructed the query, but the resulting records only show the changes within the previous month.  Moving the WHERE clause to the end restricts the output to exclude the most recent effective date prior to the previous month.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "BILL2".*
FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL"
LEFT JOIN

  /*  Returns all rows for each unit with effective date >= maximum prior effective date and effective date < current month */
  (
  SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber" AS "UNITNO",
    UPPER("UNITS"."SpecNoDescription") AS "TS_DESCR",
    "UNITS"."UsingDepartment" AS "USING_DEPT",
    "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" AS "OWNING_DEPT",
    "BILL"."BILLING_CODE",
    "BILL"."EFF_DT",
    "BILL"."UNIT_ID"
  FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS" ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" =  "UNITS"."UNITID"
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC("BILL"."EFF_DT"), 'YYYYMM'), '999999') < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0)), 'YYYYMM'), '999999') AND
"UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" = '580' AND
"BILL"."EFF_DT" >=

    /*  Returns maximum effective date prior to previous month for each unit  */
    (
    SELECT MAX("BILL3"."EFF_DT")
    FROM "MFIVE"."BILL_UNIT_ACCT" "BILL3"
    WHERE "BILL3"."UNIT_ID" = "BILL"."UNIT_ID" AND
      TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC("BILL3"."EFF_DT"), 'YYYYMM'), '999999') < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)), 'YYYYMM'), '999999')
    GROUP BY "BILL3"."UNIT_ID"
    ) 

  ) BILL2

ON "BILL"."UNIT_ID" = "BILL2"."UNIT_ID"
WHERE TO_CHAR("BILL"."EFF_DT", 'YYYYMM') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), 'YYYYMM')
ORDER BY "BILL2"."UNITNO", "BILL2"."EFF_DT" DESC
```